# How its corrected apply the Newton Rhapson metod?

Tags: calculus

Im looking to apply the Newton-Rhapson method to this function:
$F(t)=0.5-e^{-2t}(1+2t)$
and the derivative
$F'(t)=4te^{-2t}$

but I dont understand how this is get, I did this:
$F(t)=0.5-e^{-2t}-2te^{-2t}$ and
$F'(t)=4te^{-2t}$

but the system isnt the same, while the book has 
$t_n=t_0-\displaystyle\frac{e^{2t}}{8t}+\displaystyle\frac{1+2t}{4t}$
I have 
$t_n=t_0-\displaystyle\frac{0.5-e^{-2t}-2te^{-2t}}{4te^{-2t}}$

It is the same or it needs to be simplified? Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint:** Multiply that last fraction by $\dfrac{e^{2t}}{e^{2t}}$ and distribute the negative. It is exactly the same, just rearranged a bit. It simplifies calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Ok, thanks for say, I havent seen why, I ever started using partial fractions..but it has no sense.

Said that, this is what is done:
$\displaystyle\frac{0.5-e^{-2t}-2te^{-2t}}{4te^{-2t}}$
$\displaystyle\frac{e^{2t}}{e^{2t}}$
$=\displaystyle\frac{0.5e^{2t}-1-2t}{4t}$
$=\displaystyle\frac{0.5e^{2t}-(1+2t)}{4t}=\displaystyle\frac{0.5e^{2t}}{4t}-\displaystyle\frac{1+2t}{4t}$

and voilá!.
Thanks a lot!